# Bug in code inline comment with URL

Tags: bug, comments

I've done it dozens of times, but this time it just completely failed.

The comment I'm talking about is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50997083/php-regex-to-ignore-group-of-characters#comment88988460_50997083)

I've checked whitespaces, etc. Hard refreshed the page and nothing special was shown, no extra spaces, nothing.

The comment I copied into my clipboard (added backslashes to show it as raw text) before it was inaccessible to me was:

> I might be old fashioned, but I don't believe regex is the cure to most things. Take a look at [`parse_url()`](php.net/manual/kln/function.parse-url.php). ...

I don't believe this functionality has changed, right? However selecting the text, it shows an extra space, which would make that syntax invalid.

My user agent:

> Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.112 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/1.91.867.48

I'm just here to report, not to complain. I would have updated my browser, but to do that would have required more than the 5 minute edit time I have due to the ffmpeg which needs to compile by source code.

So it could have been an issue on my end, but perhaps the team has received more issues (that I couldn't find) here on meta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed the http:// (or https://). That makes the difference if the sequence of characters is considered to be a link.

Adding https:// to the comment, like so

> `` I might be old fashioned, but I don't believe regex is the cure to most things. Take a look at [`parse_url()`](https://php.net/manual/kln/function.parse-url.php). ... ``

should work.

See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: I might be old fashioned, but I don't believe regex is the cure to most things. Take a look at [`parse_url()`](https://php.net/manual/kln/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: Can't believe I missed something.. so simple. I almost feel stupid.